# Steel's method for nonparametric multiple comparison with control

Tags: references, nonparametric

Where can I find details of Steel's method for nonparametric multiple comparison with control on line?

Answer (score 2):

A google scholar search for "Steel Multiple Comparisons" quickly yields the paper you're looking [for](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2527654).